# Text is gradually shifting downward, no longer flush with top of text box

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a series of labels and input boxes / select lists on a page. With each row , the label shifts a little more away from the top of the input box / select list. I want the top of the label flush with the top of the input box for every row.

I'm sure it's CSS-related but what do I need to change to fix this issue?

This shows the issue. At the top, you can see the text appears aligned with the box but each line shifts a little more away from the top. [image]

This shows the CSS applied to the labels. [image]

This  shows the CSS  applied to the select list. Both at the 5th items from the top.
[image]

This is the typical HTML for each row...

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        <label for="DOB">DOB</label>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DOB must be a date." data-val-required="The DOB field is required." id="DOB" name="DOB" type="date" value="1/23/1945" />
        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DOB" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the HTML structure of each row?

Comment: is there a  particular reason the labels are in a separate div?

Comment: @thom - the markup is generated from ASP.NET MVC and its scaffolding. It would be nice to not change what's generated for us.

Comment: i would have a look in firebug or webkit developer to see what is out of alignment. you may need to set some sizes on the divs and display:inline-block or float.

Comment: if the label is throwing it off you could use top:0 - text-top will just align the text to the top of <label> - you may need <label> at the top of <div> instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you do not have height or line-height set on either labels or fields. I believe you will need to specify both height and line-height so that each takes up the same amount of vertical space.